# A simple terminal-based trading game in C

Tags: c, game

I wrote this a few months ago as my first "serious" C program (I've used JS for a few years). It's a simple resource collecting and trading game (based off one I made in HTML/JS), that takes input in the form of some simple commands.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct trade_like {
    int8_t buy_item;
    int8_t sell_item;
    uint64_t buy_amount;
    uint64_t sell_amount;
    int16_t timer;
};

struct upgrade {
    int8_t thread;
    int8_t id;
};

void shorten_number(char *dest, uint64_t number) {
    if (number >= 1000000000000) {
        sprintf(dest, "%.2fT", fmin((double) number / 1000000000000.0, 999.99));
    } else if (number >= 1000000000) {
        sprintf(dest, "%.2fB", fmin((double) number / 1000000000.0, 999.99));
    } else if (number >= 1000000) {
        sprintf(dest, "%.2fM", fmin((double) number / 1000000.0, 999.99));
    } else if (number >= 1000) {
        sprintf(dest, "%.2fK", fmin((double) number / 1000.0, 999.99));
    } else {
        sprintf(dest, "%d", number);
    }

    return;
}

void print_resources(uint64_t resources[], struct trade_like trades[], struct trade_like deals[], struct upgrade upgrades[]) {
    char amounts[9][10];
    char trade_list[5][48];
    char deal_list[3][48];
    char upgrade_list[9][36];

    char names[9][8] = {"Wood", "Stone", "Coal", "Iron", "Copper", "Silver", "Gold", "Diamond", "Emerald"};
    char upper_names[9][8] = {"WOOD", "STONE", "COAL", "IRON", "COPPER", "SILVER", "GOLD", "DIAMOND", "EMERALD"};
    char unlock_costs[8][2][16] = {
        {"Wood (200)", "Coal (40)"},
        {"Stone (400)", "Coal (80)"},
        {"Stone (200)", "Iron (100)"},
        {"Iron (300)", "Copper (50)"},
        {"Stone (1.00K)", "Iron (400)"},
        {"Copper (500)", "Coal (300)"},
        {"Iron (1.00K)", "Silver (400)"},
        {"Diamond (200)", "Silver (100)"}
    };
    char multiplier_levels[7][8] = {"+10%", "+25%", "+75%", "DOUBLE", "LOTS OF", "TONS OF"};
    int16_t base_cost[7] = {200, 500, 1500, 4000, 10000, 20000};

    memset(trade_list, '\0', sizeof(trade_list[0][0]) * 240);
    memset(deal_list, '\0', sizeof(deal_list[0][0]) * 144);
    memset(upgrade_list, '\0', sizeof(upgrade_list[0][0]) * 324);

    printf("\033[F\033[A\033[A\033[A\033[A\033[A\033[A\033[A\033[A\033[A\033[A\033[A");

    for (int8_t i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        shorten_number(amounts[i], resources[i]);
    }

    for (int8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (trades[i].timer >= 0) {
            char sell_string[10];
            char buy_string[10];

            shorten_number(sell_string, trades[i].sell_amount);
            shorten_number(buy_string, trades[i].buy_amount);

            sprintf(trade_list[i], "[%d] %s (%s) -> %s (%s)", i + 1, names[trades[i].sell_item], sell_string, names[trades[i].buy_item], buy_string);
        }
    }

    for (int8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (deals[i].timer >= 0) {
            char sell_string[10];
            char buy_string[10];

            shorten_number(sell_string, deals[i].sell_amount);
            shorten_number(buy_string, deals[i].buy_amount);

            sprintf(deal_list[i], "[%d] %s (%s) -> %s (%s)", i + 1, names[deals[i].sell_item], sell_string, names[deals[i].buy_item], buy_string);
        }
    }

    if (upgrades[0].thread != -1) {
        sprintf(upgrade_list[0], "MINE %s", upper_names[upgrades[0].id + 1]);
        sprintf(upgrade_list[1], "   %s", unlock_costs[upgrades[0].id][0]);
        sprintf(upgrade_list[2], "   %s", unlock_costs[upgrades[0].id][1]);
    }

    if (upgrades[1].thread != -1) {
        sprintf(upgrade_list[4], "%s %s", multiplier_levels[(int8_t) ((double) upgrades[1].id / 9.0)], upper_names[upgrades[1].id % 9]);

        char cost_string[10];

        shorten_number(cost_string, (double) base_cost[(int8_t) upgrades[1].id / 9] * (1.0 - 0.1 * (upgrades[1].id % 9)));

        sprintf(upgrade_list[5], "   %s (%s)", names[upgrades[1].id % 9], cost_string);
    }

    if (upgrades[2].thread == 2) {
        sprintf(upgrade_list[7], "AUTO-%s", upper_names[upgrades[2].id]);
        if (upgrades[2].id == 4) {
            strcpy(upgrade_list[8], "   Gold (200)");
        }
        sprintf(upgrade_list[8], "   %s (200)", names[upgrades[2].id + 2]);
    } else if (upgrades[2].thread == 3) {
        sprintf(upgrade_list[7], "%s/%s DEALS", upper_names[upgrades[2].id * 2], upper_names[upgrades[2].id * 2 + 1]);

        char cost_string[10];

        shorten_number(cost_string, 1750 - 375 * upgrades[2].id);

        sprintf(upgrade_list[8], "   %s (%s)", names[upgrades[2].id * 2 + 1], cost_string);
    }

    printf(
        "  Wood:     %-9s%-44s%-36s\n  Stone:    %-9s%-44s%-36s\n  Coal:     %-9s%-44s%-36s\n  Iron:     %-9s%-44s%-36s\n  Copper:   %-9s%-44s%-36s\n  Silver:   %-9s%-44s%-36s\n  Gold:     %-9s%-44s%-36s\n  Diamond:  %-9s%-44s%-36s\n  Emerald:  %-9s%-44s%-36s\n\n\n\n >>                         \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b",
        amounts[0], trade_list[0], upgrade_list[0], amounts[1], trade_list[1], upgrade_list[1], amounts[2], trade_list[2], upgrade_list[2],
        amounts[3], trade_list[3], upgrade_list[3], amounts[4], trade_list[4], upgrade_list[4], amounts[5], " ", upgrade_list[5],
        amounts[6], deal_list[0], upgrade_list[6], amounts[7], deal_list[1], upgrade_list[7], amounts[8], deal_list[2], upgrade_list[8]
    );

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int8_t unlocked = 0;
    uint64_t resources[9] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    double multipliers[9] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    int8_t auto_level = 0;

    int16_t item_costs[9] = {1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 40, 80, 200, 875};

    char names[9][8] = {"Wood", "Stone", "Coal", "Iron", "Copper", "Silver", "Gold", "Diamond", "Emerald"};

    struct trade_like trades[5];
    struct trade_like deals[3];

    int8_t trade_tick = 0;
    int8_t deal_tick = 0;
    int8_t unlocked_deals = 0;

    for (int8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        trades[i].timer = -1;
        
        if (i < 3) {
            deals[i].timer = -1;
        }
    }

    struct upgrade upgrades[3];

    upgrades[0].thread = 0;
    upgrades[0].id = 0;

    upgrades[0].thread = -1;
    upgrades[1].thread = -1;
    upgrades[2].thread = -1;

    int64_t turn_count = 0;

    char words_redo[4][24];

    srand(time(NULL));

    strcpy(words_redo[0], "collect");
    strcpy(words_redo[1], "wood");
    memset(words_redo[2], '\0', sizeof(words_redo[2][0]) * 48);

    printf("MERCHANT 2.0.0 [TERMINAL EDITION]\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n  Enter 'collect wood' to begin playing!\n\n\n\033[A");

    char input[24];

    while (strncmp(input, "quit\n", 5) != 0 && strncmp(input, "exit\n", 5) != 0 && strncmp(input, "q\n", 2) != 0 && strncmp(input, "x\n", 2) != 0) {
        print_resources(resources, trades, deals, upgrades);

        fgets(input, 24, stdin);

        printf("\033[F\033[A\033[A                                                  \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");

        char words[4][24];
        int8_t word_count = 0;
        int8_t within_word = 0;

        memset(words[0], '\0', sizeof(words[0][0]) * 96);

        for (int8_t i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            if (input[i] == '\n' || input[i] == '\0') {
                break;
            } else if (input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'z' || input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'Z' || input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9' || input[i] == '-' || input[i] == '_') {
                words[word_count][within_word++] = input[i];
            } else {
                if (within_word != 0) {
                    word_count++;
                    within_word = 0;

                    if (word_count == 4) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (strncmp(words[0], "redo\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "r\0", 2) == 0 || words[0][0] == '\0') {
            strcpy(words[0], words_redo[0]);
            strcpy(words[1], words_redo[1]);
            strcpy(words[2], words_redo[2]);
            strcpy(words[3], words_redo[3]);
        }

        if (strncmp(words[0], "collect\0", 8) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "col\0", 4) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "c\0", 2) == 0) {
            int16_t collect_amount;

            if (words[1][0] == '\0' || words[2][0] != '\0') {
                printf("ERR: Expected one argument (resource name)\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            if (strncmp(words[1], "wood\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "w\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked < 0) {
                    printf("ERR: You haven't unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                collect_amount = (int16_t) (floorf(multipliers[0]) + (rand() < RAND_MAX * (multipliers[0] - floorf(multipliers[0]))));

                resources[0] += collect_amount;
                printf("Collected %d wood", collect_amount);
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "stone\0", 6) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "s\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked < 1) {
                    printf("ERR: You haven't unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                collect_amount = (int16_t) (floorf(multipliers[1]) + (rand() < RAND_MAX * (multipliers[1] - floorf(multipliers[1]))));

                resources[1] += collect_amount;
                printf("Collected %d stone", collect_amount);
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "coal\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "c\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked < 2) {
                    printf("ERR: You haven't unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                collect_amount = (int16_t) (floorf(multipliers[2]) + (rand() < RAND_MAX * (multipliers[2] - floorf(multipliers[2]))));

                resources[2] += collect_amount;
                printf("Collected %d coal", collect_amount);
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "iron\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "i\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked < 3) {
                    printf("ERR: You haven't unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                collect_amount = (int16_t) (floorf(multipliers[3]) + (rand() < RAND_MAX * (multipliers[3] - floorf(multipliers[3]))));

                resources[3] += collect_amount;
                printf("Collected %d iron", collect_amount);
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "copper\0", 7) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "cp\0", 3) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "cr\0", 3) == 0) {
                if (unlocked < 4) {
                    printf("ERR: You haven't unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                collect_amount = (int16_t) (floorf(multipliers[4]) + (rand() < RAND_MAX * (multipliers[4] - floorf(multipliers[4]))));

                resources[4] += collect_amount;
                printf("Collected %d copper", collect_amount);
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "silver\0", 7) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "si\0", 3) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "sv\0", 3) == 0) {
                if (unlocked < 5) {
                    printf("ERR: You haven't unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                collect_amount = (int16_t) (floorf(multipliers[5]) + (rand() < RAND_MAX * (multipliers[5] - floorf(multipliers[5]))));

                resources[5] += collect_amount;
                printf("Collected %d silver", collect_amount);
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "gold\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "g\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked < 6) {
                    printf("ERR: You haven't unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                collect_amount = (int16_t) (floorf(multipliers[6]) + (rand() < RAND_MAX * (multipliers[6] - floorf(multipliers[6]))));

                resources[6] += collect_amount;
                printf("Collected %d gold", collect_amount);
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "diamond\0", 8) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "d\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked < 7) {
                    printf("ERR: You haven't unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                collect_amount = (int16_t) (floorf(multipliers[7]) + (rand() < RAND_MAX * (multipliers[7] - floorf(multipliers[7]))));

                resources[7] += collect_amount;
                printf("Collected %d diamond", collect_amount);
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "emerald\0", 8) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "e\0", 2) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "m\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked < 8) {
                    printf("ERR: You haven't unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                collect_amount = (int16_t) (floorf(multipliers[8]) + (rand() < RAND_MAX * (multipliers[8] - floorf(multipliers[8]))));

                resources[8] += collect_amount;
                printf("Collected %d emerald", collect_amount);
            } else {
                printf("ERR: Unknown resource\n\n");
                continue;
            }
        } else if (strncmp(words[0], "trade\0", 6) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "tr\0", 3) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "t\0", 2) == 0) {
            if (words[1][0] == '\0' || words[2][0] != '\0') {
                printf("ERR: Expected one argument (trade id)\n\n");
                continue;
            }
            
            if (words[1][1] != '\0' || words[1][0] < '1' || words[1][0] > '5') {
                printf("ERR: Invalid trade id\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            int8_t trade = words[1][0] - 49;

            if (trades[trade].timer == -1) {
                printf("ERR: There is no trade with that id\n\n");
                continue;
            } else if (resources[trades[trade].sell_item] < trades[trade].sell_amount) {
                printf("ERR: You can't afford that trade\n\n");
                continue;
            } else {
                resources[trades[trade].buy_item] += trades[trade].buy_amount;
                resources[trades[trade].sell_item] -= trades[trade].sell_amount;

                trades[trade].timer = fmax(trades[trade].timer - (int16_t) ((trades[trade].buy_amount / resources[trades[trade].buy_item]) * 4), -1);

                printf("Trade #1: %s (%d) -> %s (%d)", names[trades[trade].sell_item], trades[trade].sell_amount, names[trades[trade].buy_item], trades[trade].buy_amount);
            }
        } else if (strncmp(words[0], "deal\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "d\0", 2) == 0) {
            if (words[1][0] == '\0' || words[2][0] != '\0') {
                printf("ERR: Expected one argument (deal id)\n\n");
                continue;
            }
            
            if (words[1][1] != '\0' || words[1][0] < '1' || words[1][0] > '3') {
                printf("ERR: Invalid deal id\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            int8_t deal = words[1][0] - 49;

            if (deals[deal].timer == -1) {
                printf("ERR: There is no deal with that id\n\n");
                continue;
            } else if (resources[deals[deal].sell_item] < deals[deal].sell_amount) {
                printf("ERR: You can't afford that deal\n\n");
                continue;
            } else {
                resources[deals[deal].buy_item] += deals[deal].buy_amount;
                resources[deals[deal].sell_item] -= deals[deal].sell_amount;

                deals[deal].timer = -1;

                printf("Deal #1: %s (%d) -> %s (%d)", names[deals[deal].sell_item], deals[deal].sell_amount, names[deals[deal].buy_item], deals[deal].buy_amount);
            }
        } else if (strncmp(words[0], "unlock\0", 7) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "unl\0", 4) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "u\0", 2) == 0) {
            if (words[1][0] == '\0' || words[2][0] != '\0') {
                printf("ERR: Expected one argument (resource id)\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            if (strncmp(words[1], "wood\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "w\0", 2) == 0) {
                printf("ERR: You have already unlocked this resource\n\n");
                continue;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "stone\0", 6) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "s\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked >= 1) {
                    printf("ERR: You have already unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (resources[0] < 200 || resources[2] < 40) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford to unlock this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[0] -= 200;
                resources[2] -= 40;

                unlocked++;

                printf("Unlocked stone");
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "coal\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "c\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked >= 2) {
                    printf("ERR: You have already unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (unlocked < 1) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot unlock this resource yet\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (resources[1] < 400 || resources[2] < 80) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford to unlock this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[1] -= 400;
                resources[2] -= 80;

                unlocked++;

                printf("Unlocked coal");
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "iron\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "i\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked >= 3) {
                    printf("ERR: You have already unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (unlocked < 2) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot unlock this resource yet\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (resources[1] < 200 || resources[3] < 100) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford to unlock this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[1] -= 200;
                resources[3] -= 100;

                unlocked++;

                printf("Unlocked iron");
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "copper\0", 7) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "cp\0", 3) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "cr\0", 3) == 0) {
                if (unlocked >= 4) {
                    printf("ERR: You have already unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (unlocked < 3) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot unlock this resource yet\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (resources[3] < 300 || resources[4] < 50) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford to unlock this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[3] -= 300;
                resources[4] -= 50;

                unlocked++;

                printf("Unlocked copper");
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "silver\0", 7) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "si\0", 3) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "sv\0", 3) == 0) {
                if (unlocked >= 5) {
                    printf("ERR: You have already unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (unlocked < 4) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot unlock this resource yet\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (resources[1] < 1000 || resources[3] < 400) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford to unlock this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[1] -= 1000;
                resources[3] -= 400;

                unlocked++;

                printf("Unlocked silver");
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "gold\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "g\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked >= 6) {
                    printf("ERR: You have already unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (unlocked < 5) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot unlock this resource yet\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (resources[4] < 500 || resources[2] < 300) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford to unlock this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[4] -= 500;
                resources[2] -= 300;

                unlocked++;

                printf("Unlocked gold");
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "diamond\0", 8) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "d\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked >= 7) {
                    printf("ERR: You have already unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (unlocked < 6) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot unlock this resource yet\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (resources[3] < 1000 || resources[5] < 400) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford to unlock this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[3] -= 1000;
                resources[5] -= 400;

                unlocked++;

                printf("Unlocked diamond");
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "emerald\0", 8) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "e\0", 2) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "m\0", 2) == 0) {
                if (unlocked == 8) {
                    printf("ERR: You have already unlocked this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (unlocked < 7) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot unlock this resource yet\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                if (resources[7] < 200 || resources[5] < 100) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford to unlock this resource\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[7] -= 200;
                resources[5] -= 100;

                unlocked++;

                printf("Unlocked emerald");
            } else {
                printf("ERR: Unknown resource\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            upgrades[0].thread = -1;
        } else if (strncmp(words[0], "multiplier\0", 11) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "multiply\0", 9) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "multi\0", 6) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "mul\0", 4) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "m\0", 2) == 0) {
            if (words[1][0] == '\0' || words[2][0] != '\0') {
                printf("ERR: Expected one argument (resource name)\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            int8_t resource;

            if (strncmp(words[1], "wood\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "w\0", 2) == 0) {
                resource = 0;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "stone\0", 6) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "s\0", 2) == 0) {
                resource = 1;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "coal\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "c\0", 2) == 0) {
                resource = 2;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "iron\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "i\0", 2) == 0) {
                resource = 3;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "copper\0", 7) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "cp\0", 3) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "cr\0", 3) == 0) {
                resource = 4;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "silver\0", 7) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "si\0", 3) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "sv\0", 3) == 0) {
                resource = 5;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "gold\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "g\0", 2) == 0) {
                resource = 6;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "diamond\0", 8) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "d\0", 2) == 0) {
                resource = 7;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "emerald\0", 8) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "e\0", 2) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "m\0", 2) == 0) {
                resource = 8;
            } else {
                printf("ERR: Unknown resource\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            if (multipliers[resource] == 1.0) {
                if (resources[resource] < 200 - 20 * resource) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford this upgrade\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[resource] -= 200 - 20 * resource;
                multipliers[resource] = 1.1;
            } else if (multipliers[resource] == 1.1) {
                if (resources[resource] < 500 - 50 * resource) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford this upgrade\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[resource] -= 500 - 50 * resource;
                multipliers[resource] = 1.25;
            } else if (multipliers[resource] == 1.25) {
                if (resources[resource] < 1500 - 150 * resource) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford this upgrade\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[resource] -= 1500 - 150 * resource;
                multipliers[resource] = 1.75;
            } else if (multipliers[resource] == 1.75) {
                if (resources[resource] < 4000 - 40 * resource) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford this upgrade\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[resource] -= 4000 - 400 * resource;
                multipliers[resource] = 2.0;
            } else if (multipliers[resource] == 2.0) {
                if (resources[resource] < 10000 - 1000 * resource) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford this upgrade\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[resource] -= 10000 - 1000 * resource;
                multipliers[resource] = 5.0;
            } else if (multipliers[resource] == 5.0) {
                if (resources[resource] < 20000 - 2000 * resource) {
                    printf("ERR: You cannot afford this upgrade\n\n");
                    continue;
                }

                resources[resource] -= 20000 - 2000 * resource;
                multipliers[resource] = 10.0;
            } else {
                printf("ERR: This resource is already at max multiplier\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            upgrades[1].thread = -1;
        } else if (strncmp(words[0], "autocollect\0", 12) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "autocol\0", 8) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "auto\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "a\0", 2) == 0) {
            if (words[1][0] == '\0' || words[2][0] != '\0') {
                printf("ERR: Expected one argument (resource)\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            int8_t level;

            if (strncmp(words[1], "wood\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "w\0", 2) == 0) {
                level = 1;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "stone\0", 6) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "s\0", 2) == 0) {
                level = 2;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "coal\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "c\0", 2) == 0) {
                level = 3;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "iron\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "i\0", 2) == 0) {
                level = 4;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "metal\0", 6) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "m\0", 2) == 0) {
                level = 5;
            } else {
                printf("ERR: Unknown or non-automatable resource\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            if (auto_level > level) {
                printf("ERR: You have already automated this resource\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            if (auto_level < level - 1) {
                printf("ERR: You cannot automate this resource yet\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            if (resources[level + 1] < 200) {
                printf("ERR: You cannot afford to automate this resource\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            auto_level = level;
            resources[level + 1] -= 200;

            upgrades[2].thread = -1;
        } else if (strncmp(words[0], "unlock-deal\0", 12) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "unlock_deal\0", 12) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "unl-d\0", 6) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "unl_d\0", 6) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "ud\0", 3) == 0 || strncmp(words[0], "l\0", 2) == 0) {
            if (words[1][0] == '\0' || words[2][0] != '\0') {
                printf("ERR: Expected one argument (resource)\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            int8_t deal;

            if (strncmp(words[1], "wood\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "w\0", 2) == 0) {
                deal = 2;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "stone\0", 6) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "s\0", 2) == 0) {
                deal = 2;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "coal\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "c\0", 2) == 0) {
                deal = 4;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "iron\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "i\0", 2) == 0) {
                deal = 4;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "copper\0", 7) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "cp\0", 3) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "cr\0", 3) == 0) {
                deal = 6;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "silver\0", 7) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "si\0", 3) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "sv\0", 3) == 0) {
                deal = 6;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "gold\0", 5) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "g\0", 2) == 0) {
                deal = 8;
            } else if (strncmp(words[1], "diamond\0", 8) == 0 || strncmp(words[1], "d\0", 2) == 0) {
                deal = 8;
            } else {
                printf("ERR: Unknown resource\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            if (deal < unlocked_deals) {
                printf("You have already unlocked these deals\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            if (unlocked_deals < deal - 2) {
                printf("You cannot unlock these deals yet\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            if (resources[deal - 1] < 2125 - (deal / 2) * 375) {
                printf("You cannot afford to unlock these deals\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            resources[deal - 1] -= 2125 - (deal / 2) * 375;
            unlocked_deals = deal;

            upgrades[2].thread = -1;
        } else {
            printf("ERR: Unknown command\n\n");
            continue;
        }

        strcpy(words_redo[0], words[0]);
        strcpy(words_redo[1], words[1]);
        strcpy(words_redo[2], words[2]);
        strcpy(words_redo[3], words[3]);

        printf("\n\n");

        if (auto_level == 1) {
            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.1) {
                resources[0]++;
            }
        } else if (auto_level == 2) {
            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.2) {
                resources[0]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.1) {
                resources[1]++;
            }
        } else if (auto_level == 3) {
            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.35) {
                resources[0]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.2) {
                resources[1]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.1) {
                resources[2]++;
            }
        } else if (auto_level == 4) {
            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.5) {
                resources[0]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.35) {
                resources[1]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.2) {
                resources[2]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.1) {
                resources[3]++;
            }
        } else if (auto_level == 5) {
            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.75) {
                resources[0]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.5) {
                resources[1]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.35) {
                resources[2]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.2) {
                resources[3]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.1) {
                resources[4]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.05) {
                resources[5]++;
            }

            if (rand() < (double) RAND_MAX * 0.01) {
                resources[6]++;
            }
        }

        if (trade_tick-- < 0) {
            for (int8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if (trades[i].timer >= 0)
                    trades[i].timer--;
            }

            if (rand() < RAND_MAX * 0.15) {
                int8_t trade = -1;

                for (int8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    if (trades[i].timer == -1) {
                        trade = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (trade != -1) {
                    trades[trade].sell_item = (int8_t) ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * (unlocked + 1));
                    trades[trade].sell_amount = (uint64_t) (resources[trades[trade].sell_item] * ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) + 0.25) + (uint64_t) (rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * 40 * multipliers[trades[trade].sell_item]);
                
                    do {
                        trades[trade].buy_item = (int8_t) ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * (fmin(unlocked, 8) + 1));

                        double random = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;

                        if (random < 0.02 && unlocked <= 5) {
                            trades[trade].buy_item += 3;
                        } else if (random < 0.2 && unlocked <= 6) {
                            trades[trade].buy_item += 2;
                        } else if (random < 0.6 && unlocked <= 7) {
                            trades[trade].buy_item += 1;
                        }
                    } while (trades[trade].buy_item == trades[trade].sell_item);

                    trades[trade].buy_amount = (uint64_t) (((trades[trade].sell_amount * item_costs[trades[trade].sell_item]) * ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * 0.6 + 0.75)) / item_costs[trades[trade].buy_item]);
                    trades[trade].timer = (int16_t) ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * 8 + 16);
                }
            }

            trade_tick = (int8_t) ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * 5) + 4;
        }

        if (unlocked_deals != 0 && deal_tick-- < 0) {
            for (int8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (deals[i].timer >= 0)
                    deals[i].timer--;
            }

            if (rand() < RAND_MAX * 0.35) {
                int8_t deal = -1;

                for (int8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (deals[i].timer == -1) {
                        deal = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (deal != -1) {
                    deals[deal].sell_item = (int8_t) ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * unlocked_deals);
                    deals[deal].sell_amount = (uint64_t) (resources[deals[deal].sell_item] * ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * 0.5 + 0.1) + (rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * 20 * multipliers[deals[deal].sell_item]);
                
                    do {
                        deals[deal].buy_item = (int8_t) ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * unlocked_deals);
                    } while (deals[deal].buy_item == deals[deal].sell_item);

                    deals[deal].buy_amount = (uint64_t) (((deals[deal].sell_amount * item_costs[deals[deal].sell_item]) * ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) + 0.6)) / item_costs[deals[deal].buy_item]);
                    deals[deal].timer = (int16_t) ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * 3 + 8);
                }
            }

            deal_tick = (int8_t) ((rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * 2) + 2;
        }

        if (upgrades[0].thread == -1) {
            if (unlocked == 0) {
                upgrades[0].thread = 0;
                upgrades[0].id = 0;
            } else if (unlocked == 1 && resources[2]) {
                upgrades[0].thread = 0;
                upgrades[0].id = 1;
            } else if (unlocked == 2 && resources[3]) {
                upgrades[0].thread = 0;
                upgrades[0].id = 2;
            } else if (unlocked == 3 && resources[4]) {
                upgrades[0].thread = 0;
                upgrades[0].id = 3;
            } else if (unlocked == 4 && resources[5]) {
                upgrades[0].thread = 0;
                upgrades[0].id = 4;
            } else if (unlocked == 5 && resources[6]) {
                upgrades[0].thread = 0;
                upgrades[0].id = 5;
            } else if (unlocked == 6 && resources[7]) {
                upgrades[0].thread = 0;
                upgrades[0].id = 6;
            } else if (unlocked == 7 && resources[8]) {
                upgrades[0].thread = 0;
                upgrades[0].id = 7;
            }
        }

        if (upgrades[1].thread == -1) {
            for (int8_t i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (multipliers[i] == 5.0 && resources[i] > 2000) {
                    upgrades[1].thread = 1;
                    upgrades[1].id = i + 45;

                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int8_t i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (multipliers[i] == 2.0 && resources[i] > 1000) {
                    upgrades[1].thread = 1;
                    upgrades[1].id = i + 36;

                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int8_t i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (multipliers[i] == 1.75 && resources[i] > 400) {
                    upgrades[1].thread = 1;
                    upgrades[1].id = i + 27;

                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int8_t i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (multipliers[i] == 1.25 && resources[i] > 150) {
                    upgrades[1].thread = 1;
                    upgrades[1].id = i + 18;

                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int8_t i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (multipliers[i] == 1.1 && resources[i] > 50) {
                    upgrades[1].thread = 1;
                    upgrades[1].id = i + 9;

                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int8_t i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (multipliers[i] == 1.0 && resources[i] > 20) {
                    upgrades[1].thread = 1;
                    upgrades[1].id = i;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (upgrades[2].thread == -1) {
            if (auto_level == 0 && unlocked >= 1 && resources[2]) {
                upgrades[2].thread = 2;
                upgrades[2].id = 0;
            } else if (auto_level == 1 && unlocked >= 2 && resources[3]) {
                upgrades[2].thread = 2;
                upgrades[2].id = 1;
            } else if (auto_level == 2 && unlocked >= 3 && resources[4]) {
                upgrades[2].thread = 2;
                upgrades[2].id = 2;
            } else if (auto_level == 3 && unlocked >= 4 && resources[5]) {
                upgrades[2].thread = 2;
                upgrades[2].id = 3;
            } else if (auto_level == 4 && unlocked >= 6) {
                upgrades[2].thread = 2;
                upgrades[2].id = 4;
            } else if (unlocked_deals == 0 && unlocked >= 1) {
                upgrades[2].thread = 3;
                upgrades[2].id = 0;
            } else if (unlocked_deals == 2 && unlocked >= 3) {
                upgrades[2].thread = 3;
                upgrades[2].id = 1;
            } else if (unlocked_deals == 4 && unlocked >= 5) {
                upgrades[2].thread = 3;
                upgrades[2].id = 2;
            } else if (unlocked_deals == 6 && unlocked >= 7) {
                upgrades[2].thread = 3;
                upgrades[2].id = 3;
            }
        }

        turn_count++;
    }

    printf("\033[F\033[A  Finished game after %d turn(s)\n\n", turn_count);

    return 0;
}
```

(Compiled on my machine (Bash, Linux VM) with `gcc -g -lm -o merchant merchant.c`)

Some things I was wondering about:

- Is there a way to get rid of all those `else if`s? Maybe a `switch` statement or `for` loop?
- Is there a better way to overwrite all of the program's previous output than just moving the cursor to overwrite it?
- Is my code readable?

First post on code review, if there's something I forgot to include let me know!

Comment: (In case of any confusion `thread` in `upgrade` doesn't refer to threads in the computer sense, it's just the word I used for "upgrade path/type")

Comment: Perfect first question, don't worry about it.

Comment: OT:  running the posted code through a compiler results in LOTs of warnings.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: OT: the posted code fails to prompt the user as to what the user should input at the `>>` prompt

Comment: PS look up for the ncurses.h / curses.h header-file, it's a library for terminal "GUI" applications, very handy.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `switch`, but be informed that using `break;` to break the loop would not work (Instead you would have to use a `goto` to break the loop.); same applies to a nested for-loop (With additional regards to `continue`, which would also have to be used in a `goto` way.), so *summa summarum*, using `if`, `else if`, `else` is the best way in your case.

Moving the cursor is the way how to do in a terminal application, totally fine.

Your code is readable, but I would suggest to outsource some code to functions, especially all this redundant checking.

PS I would probably separate the input code from the output code. Meaning, I would write a function only for user inputs, one function for processing those inputs and another function for outputs.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get rid of all those else ifs? Maybe a switch statement or for loop?

Certainly.

With `if (strncmp(words[0], "redo\0", ....` consider a table of pairs of string and function.

```
// Something like 
for (i=0; i<table_size; i++) {
  if (my_compare(words[0], table[i].s)) {
    table[i].f(state_data, words, ....);  // do whatever per helper function
    break;
  }
}
if (i == table_size) my_handle_no_match();
```

With `shorten_number()`:

To get a correct answer is tricky mixing 64-bit integer math with `double`.

Example: (Note original code provides errant results with large values and near 999.995+*10^3x)

```
// Reduce to "1.00x" to "999.99x"
void shorten_number(char *dest, uint64_t number) {
  if (number < 1000) {
    sprintf(dest, "%d", (int) number);
    return;
  }
  static const char suffix[] = " KMBTqQ"; // or maybe metric " kMGTPEZY"
  int suffix_index = 0;
  double scale = 1.0;

  while (number/scale >= 999.995) {
    scale *= 1000.0;
    suffix_index++;
  }
  sprintf(dest, "%.2f%c", number / scale, suffix[suffix_index]);
}
```

---

> Is there a better way to overwrite all of the program's previous output than just moving the cursor to overwrite it?

C has no standard way to overwrite previous output.   Any solution is specific to the terminal type.

Rather than `printf("\033[F\033[A\033[A ...`, consider making a helper function `erase_line()` that does the same, but with this abstraction allows to more easily identify and maintain implementation specific code.

Same applies for any place an ANSI escape sequence is used - abstract it.

---

> Is my code readable?

Mostly yes.

I find the 4 space indent excessive over 2, yet such style issues are best decided by your group's style guide.

`main()` is *long*.  Perhaps break it up.

Too many naked [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

---

**Zero data cleanly**

Rather than potentially miscalculated code

```
// memset(trade_list, '\0', sizeof(trade_list[0][0]) * 240);
memset(trade_list, 0, sizeof trade_list);
```

or initialize with zero

```
// char trade_list[5][48];
char trade_list[5][48] = { 0 };
```

**Wrong format**

```
uint64_t number
// at this point number < 1000, but still type uint64_t
// sprintf(dest, "%d", number);
sprintf(dest, "%d", (int) number);
// or 
sprintf(dest, "%" PRIu64, number);
```

This hints at a serious weakness in OP's efforts: not fully enabling all warnings as a good well enabled compiler will warn about this.  This is the **most important feedback**: enable all warnings and let your compiler give your rapid feedback.